# How to get last transactions made to a non-wallet bitcoin address?

Tags: wallet, blockchain, bitcoind, confirmations

[I know I can](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/11760/11136) rebuild my block index by setting `txindex=1` in my bitcoin.conf file and restart bitcoind with `-reindex` so that I can view non-wallet transactions using:

```
bitcoind getrawtransaction a93a668d9332e21d51380c7251bbf5ad47295ca9795e0ad6f2fe8d63b76af9aa 1
```

I'm currently in another situation however, in which I only have the recipient address. So my question is, can I list all transactions that have been received by a certain address, preferably including the confirmations that this transaction has gotten?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There is a blockchain tool call Obelisk which works like bitcoind in effect, they do have [public servers](https://wiki.unsystem.net/en/index.php/Obelisk/Servers) open to save you having to download the whole blockchain. You need to install obelisk and sx tools (same authors)..

Info:  http://libbitcoin.dyne.org/  also  http://sx.dyne.org/history.html
sx tools Git:  https://github.com/spesmilo/sx
Obelisk Git:  https://github.com/libbitcoin/obelisk/